# How to convert polygon data into line segments using PostGIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

I have a polygon data table in PostgreSQL/PostGIS. Now I need to convert this Polygon data into its corresponding line segments. Can anybody tell  me how to convert it using PostGIS queries.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 26):

Generally, converting polygon to line may be not straightforward because [there is no one-to-one mapping](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2006-September/013316.html) and various elements of polygon map to different linestring (exterior ring, interior rings, etc.).

Considering that, you will need to split each of those separately following possible approach like this:

```
SELECT ST_AsText( ST_MakeLine(sp,ep) )
FROM
   -- extract the endpoints for every 2-point line segment for each linestring
   (SELECT
      ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom)-1)) as sp,
      ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(2, ST_NPoints(geom)  )) as ep
    FROM
       -- extract the individual linestrings
      (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Boundary(geom))).geom
       FROM mypolygontable
       ) AS linestrings
    ) AS segments;
```

depending on what polygon data are stored in `mypolygontable`, you may want to dump not only the boundary (as above using `ST_Boundary`) but also other elements. The code above with more detailed overview is taken from the postgis-users list: [Split a polygon to N linestrings](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2010-January/025754.html)

There is also a generic approach to the problem explained in [Exploding a linestring or polygon into individual vectors in PostGIS](http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/postgis_tips_tricks/128/exploding-a-linestring-or-polygon-into-individual-vectors-in-postgis/)

Answer (score -2):

This is the first hit on google when you search this problem. I don't know if so much time has passed a function has been created since, but for future googlers ST_ExteriorRings(geom) worked great for me.
http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ExteriorRing.html

```
SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(ST_Dump(geom)).geom)
FROM foo
```

Comment: @DonaldDuck The answer is not 100% correct. The function name is `ST_ExteriorRing`, not `ST_ExteriorRings` (note the trailing `s`). It generates a single linestring instead of multiple line segments. It furthermore excludes the boundaries of holes. It also fails on multipolygons.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.